# AutocompleteTextview is not showing suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I customized the autocomplete textview, which shows suggestions before typing anything. But once I type on the textview, it doesnt filter the suggestions, why this is happening..

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    /**
     * @param context
     */

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused && getAdapter() != null) {
            performFiltering(getText(), 0);
            showDropDown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I pasted the customized autocompletetextview

Comment: It filters the suggestions in the beginning. But as soon as I type something, filtering is gone